# Vibration sensor for arduino

Tags: sensors

I need vibration sensor for my project. I have found many sensors similar to [this one](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/9196). But it seems, that this sensor outputs only zeros for "non-hit" state and ones for "hit state". And I need something that can output levels of vibration, not only presence/abscense.

So is there any high-resolution vibration sensor for arduino?

Thank you!

Comment: The search term you are looking for is: "Accelerometer".  A common one is the ADXL345

Comment: Using the sensor, you can write the software that checks the amount of on's per second, effectively giving you the frequency of the vibration.

Comment: But are you looking to get the amplitude? (Intensity of the vibration)

Comment: Sounds like a dedicated Arduino would be necessary to gather this information and process it, then send it to another for the ultimate utilization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume the OP wants the frequency of the vibration, which an accelerometer such as the ADXL345 won't give.

I have two workarounds: if the expected vibration frequency is low, say, under 100Hz, use instead an on/off vibration sensor (adafruit has them for under a dollar) and count the number of transitions. If it's more, how about a microphone and a band-pass filter?

Comment: That would seem to require that the Arduino has nothing else to do but count pulses.  Maybe one could do that part of the job then feed the results to another.

Answer (score 0):

The MPU-6050 is a very low-price 3 axis gyroscope and accelerometer with both SPI and I2C interface options.

I found mine here:  https://smile.amazon.com/gp/product/B00KKR9ORI

---

EDIT:  Removed statement that it is accurate enough for this, based on comment.

Comment: The MPU-6050 is horrible for detecting vibrating motion. It is so innacurate! This module shouldn't be used for the purpose of the person's project.

Comment: Message received.  Thank you for handling this as a comment.  I added an edit to this effect.