# Looking for help with an improved vibration sensing method for Arduino

Tags: sensors

I am trying to test how vibration waves move through different material...ie how sensitive certain components are.
I am needing a vibration sensor that will send me back some kind of measurement say in the form of an integer between 1 and (a number).

I have tried the 801S with an Arduino board and it was successful. The problem though is it just returns a 1 for vibration and 0 for none. To get the results I had to keep retesting and moving the material further and further away to get it to fail.

I also tried a HiLetgo piezoelectric analog sensor. It does return a number...but the results are all over the place...from 5 to 250. I have a device that supplies a consistent "tap" to be measured...so the HiLetgo had to be letgo.

I did research SE and found this question [Vibration sensor for arduino](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/11773/vibration-sensor-for-arduino) but it does not answer my question.

Comment: not a question about Arduino ... your question is off topic here

Comment: The sensor is for an Arduino.

Comment: Did you try with a microphone module it might pick up back ground noise too, better to do a FFT hmm.  Microphone module has a prebuilt in op amp to give analog values dc biased because Arduino picks only dc voltage values.

Comment: `The sensor is for an Arduino` that does not make it an Arduino specific question ... the same sensor could be used on a Raspberry Pi or any other microcontroller .... it's similar to having a question about a camping trailer roof and asking at a Porsche site because you are using a Porsche to pull the trailer

Comment: It is unclear how exactly you measured with the piezoelectric sensor. A vibration is a wave, thus the piezoelectric sensor will give you that wave in a specific range. To get something like vibration amplitude you would need to do further processing of the data/wave. You can do this in your code by finding the min and max value in a time interval and calculating the difference

Comment: @jsotola Look its a sensor for my Arduino board. Plain and simple. Just like the tag that says "Sensor". Whats the point of a "sensor" tag in the Arduino forum? Is a question about an ESP32 also not valid?

Comment: @chrisl I was just doing an analogRead(onThePin).  Are you saying I need to say: Start a process of recording and then do the tetst. Stop. and the process the measurments?

Comment: A vibration is when the body moves rapidly back and forth. Thus the signal will also rapidly move back and forth. In fact - since you want to measure "how vibration waves move through different material" - the vibration wave is just a sound wave in that material. A sound wave is an oscillating signal (look at the wave from any song or speech that you have). The sensor just gives you this wave. If you want the amplitude of the wave you would need to measure the wave values for a specific amount of time (at least one period of the wanted frequency) and then calculate the diff between min and max

Comment: So basically the sensor was probably totally ok. You just need to interpret the data in the correct way.

Comment: @chrisl Makes total sense...will give it another go.

Comment: `Whats the point of a "sensor" tag in the Arduino forum?` ... it is for a questions like `how to use sensor XYZ with an Arduino?` or `is sensor XYZ suitable for use with Arduino?` ... it is not for `which sensor should I use?`

Comment: @jsotola Your not helping...as a matter of fact your rather rude and a hinderance. I never asked which sensor to use. I was asking for suggestions....not insults.

Comment: @ChrisCatignani I am not trying to insult you ... my apologies to you if it made you feel that way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some experiments a year or so ago to sense vibration through a (physical) office desk top using the inbuilt accelerometer and gyroscope of an Arduino Uno Wi-Fi Rev2. That chip is an [LSM6DSM](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/lsm6dsm.pdf) but I would think that any such module (e.g., [MPU6050](https://www.cdiweb.com/datasheets/invensense/mpu-6050_datasheet_v3%204.pdf)) connected to any Arduino could be useful.

There’s a good [comparison article](https://www.seeedstudio.com/blog/2020/01/07/vibration-sensors-types-how-to-use-with-arduino-and-raspberry-pi/) at Seeed Studios introducing vibration sensors for Arduino.

Update. Looking at the similar question linked by the OP I see several comments that the MPU6050 which I suggested  would have poor resolution. You may have to study data sheets (or experiment) to find the best  device for your purpose.

Second update. This [white paper](https://www.ni.com/en-au/innovations/white-papers/06/measuring-vibration-with-accelerometers.html), “Measuring vibration with accelerometers” has some good engineering notes about selecting suitable accelerometers for different purposes.

Comment: Thanks for your answer...

Comment: The STMicro IMU chip can be set up in a number of ways.  It's complex enough to seek the benefits of using the STMicro IDE to simplify its configuration.  And that would put this project onto an STMicro development board (not an Arduino). The short of it is, we don't know what type of testing you are doing.  For example are you interested in detecting a hammer hit or are you interested in how long the vibration lasts and at what frequencies. The answers dictate how the IMU is setup or even if an IMU is a solution to your problem.

Comment: @st2000 Im wanting to measure the signal strength through various materials. For example...I would expect the signal to be higher through rock versus a sponge.

Comment: Briefly, IMUs are normally used for much slower changes in force.  A tilt compensating compass or in a quadcopter. I think you can speed up the sampling time in that STMicro IMU.  But I don't know if that will be enough.  I think STMicro also makes an "X" series of sensors w/smarts built in.  You might be able to program those STMicro sensor to detect vibrations specifically. If you are designing a product maybe this is worth looking into. If this is a one-off project, then maybe just adjusting the 801S's sensitivity and repeating the test.

Comment: @st2000 saying that “IMUs are normally used for much slower changes in force.” is maybe a generalization? The lsm6dsm I mentioned specifically has vibration monitoring listed as an application. There are also papers using  cheap sensors for vibration analysis (link to follow…)

Comment: e.g., https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Duc-Nguyen-113/publication/326032887_Low-Cost_Vibration_Measurement_for_Behavior_of_Small-Scale_Steel_Modeling_using_MEMS_Raspberry_Pi-3_and_Arduino_Mega_2560/links/5bad5b99299bf13e6051db9a/Low-Cost-Vibration-Measurement-for-Behavior-of-Small-Scale-Steel-Modeling-using-MEMS-Raspberry-Pi-3-and-Arduino-Mega-2560.pdf

Comment: Agreed. My thinking was vibrations in a bridge are slower than vibrations in a truck chassis are slower than vibrations in a jet engine.  And an IMU may not be the best choice if interested in the higher frequencies.  But I think I understand the end game a bit better now.  That's why I suggested repeating the test while adjusting the 801S's sensitivity.  Actually, I think I'd automate it having the Arduino controlling the 801S's pot using a [controllable volume module](https://www.adafruit.com/product/4570).

Comment: @st2000 I follow you. That’s worth writing up as an answer.